# RxJS Forkjoin never emits even with complete() call

Tags: angular, rxjs

Working in Angular 13 so rxjs 6.6 and I'm confused by the following code that doesn't work with forkJoin.  The forkJoin never emits.  But if I change the of() to timer(0) (or really timer of any value) it does emit.

Yes I can change to combineLatest but I'm trying to understand why the code doesn't work not just how to work around the issue.

```
function testOne$(): Observable<string> {
  const s = new Subject<string>();
  of(1000).subscribe(
    (val) => {
      s.next("Yo!");
      s.complete();
    }
  )
  return s.asObservable();
}

function testTwo$(): Observable<string> {
  const s = new Subject<string>();
  of(2000).subscribe(
    (val) => {
      s.next("Yea ?");
      s.complete();
    }
  )
  return s.asObservable();
}

forkJoin(
  { one: testOne$(),
  two: testTwo$() }  
).subscribe(
  (res) => {
    console.warn(res)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`of(1000)` is an observable that emits 1000 and then completes **synchronously**

So:

```ts
function testOne$(): Observable<string> {
  const s = new Subject<string>();
  of(1000).subscribe(
    (val) => {
      s.next("Yo!");
      s.complete(); // This line is run before...
    }
  )
  // before we get to this line.
  // Right now, s is a completed and closed observable.
  return s.asObservable();
}
```

However `timer(0)` uses an `asynchronous` scheduler, even if you give it zero milliseconds. It still gets scheduled via JS's event loop. Therefore, all the synchronous code will run first and the `forkJoin` will be handed an observable that hasn't closed yet.

In RxJS `Subject`s act as the mediator for multicasting and also as a means of transitioning imperative and declarative RxJS code. The boundaries between two two styles of coding is fraught with potential foot-guns. You've run into one of them.

If I saw this type of code anywhere in a code review, I'd reject pretty quickly if it wasn't accompanied with a good reason for why the transition couldn't be done in a more principled manner. I can't really advise you here since it's clear you've simplified from a more complex problem.

Otherwise, you'd just write:

```ts
function testOne$(): Observable<string> {
  return of("Yo!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. yes this Simpler code to get information. I know how to fix it now I just wasn't seeing why it was doing it.